# Application Design: Multipurpose streaming server to android application

Tags: android, streaming, audio-streaming, server, application-design

I want to build an android streaming application from my server. And  i've been wondering how to design this server.

On one side, i need the server to stream audios for me, and i understood that the most comfortable way to play streams in android is by the MediaPlayer class which streams from HTTP urls.

On the other side, i need the server to serve other purposes as well, such as sending images of albums when client asks, or just notify the client when something is happening..

What is the best way to design the server?

Having an HTTP server that handles mp3 files requests and other requests differently?
Having a TCP server which handles HTTP requests for mp3 file as HTTP server? Some other way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP standards includes a "content/type" in its header. What more do you need? It can specify audio/video/image/HTML/XML etc using the standard protocol, and you can extend it if necessary.

It sounds like you need to read this:

http://httpd.apache.org/

Apache is one of many servers available, but it is probably the most widely used and should suit your needs.